# Leer una celda especifica de un archivo de Excel con Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Comunidad necesito su ayuda, existe alguna manera de leer una celda en un archivo de excel con Java? Seria algo como especificándole la columna y la fila en la que se encuentra la información que deseo leer. Agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando un poco llegue a esta solución, la cual es muy dinámica por que toma muchos valores desde un archivo Config.properties:

```
package manager.files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class AdminDocExcel {

    String rutaArchivo;
    String hojaExcel;
    String nombreArchivoExcel;
    String celdaExcel;
    String datoExcel;

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    /**
     * Metodo que permite obtener el valor de las propiedades que se encuentra en el
     * archivo config.properties.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void getProperties() throws IOException {
        InputStream entrada = new FileInputStream("Config.properties");
        prop.load(entrada);

        try {
            rutaArchivo = prop.getProperty("rutaArchivo");
            hojaExcel = prop.getProperty("hojaArchivoExcel");
            celdaExcel = prop.getProperty("celdaArchivoExcel");
            if (rutaArchivo == null) {
                System.out.println("No se encuentra la propiedad rutaArchivo en el archivo de properties");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Excepcion controlada al intentar cargar la propiedad rutaArchivo del archivo de properties");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Funcion que obtiene la informacion de una celda especifica de un archivo de
     * Excel, no puede ser el resultado de una funcion
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String objManagerFileExcel() throws IOException {
        getProperties();

        File carpeta = new File(rutaArchivo);
        if (carpeta.exists()) {
            nombreArchivoExcel = carpeta.getName();
            try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(rutaArchivo))) {

                // Lee el archivo de Excel
                XSSFWorkbook excelBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                // Obtiene la hoja del archivo de Excel
                XSSFSheet excelPage = excelBook.getSheet(hojaExcel);

                // Obtiene la referencia de la celda que debe seleccionar
                CellReference ref = new CellReference(celdaExcel);
                // Obtiene la fila dependiendo la celda que se configura en el archivo config.properties
                Row fila = excelPage.getRow(ref.getRow());
                if (fila != null) {
                    // Obtiene la columna dependiendo la celda que se configura en el archivo config.properties
                    Cell columna = fila.getCell(ref.getCol());
                    // Obtiene la informacion que tiene la celda pero no puede ser el resultado de una formula
                    datoExcel = columna.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                    System.out.println("La informacion es: " + datoExcel);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error Controlado");
                e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encuentra ningun archivo en la ruta especificada");
        }
        // Retorna el dato que se encuentra en la celda.
        return datoExcel;
    }
}
```

En el archivo Config.properties se debe añadir ciertos parametros como estos:

```
rutaArchivo=......\\Data.xlsx
hojaArchivoExcel=Hoja1
celdaArchivoExcel=E4
```

Para probarlos se crea la clase main y se coloca:

```
public class Ejecucion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        AdminDocExcel objAdminDocExcel;
        objAdminDocExcel = new AdminDocExcel();
        objAdminDocExcel.objManagerFileExcel();
    }

}
```

La única condición es que la celda que se va a leer en el archivo de Excel este en formato de texto.

Comment: Deberías mejorar tu pregunta, pues es pobre en contenido, añade que intentaste o hiciste y dudas claras

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esta solución sea de mucha utilidad, adjunto el método que lee el archivo, obtiene las filas del archivo y el que devuelve el resultado de la fila y la columna específica.

```
public void leerArchivo() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    String path = "./datos/archivo.xlsx";
    File file = new File(path);
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
    Iterator<Row> rows = null;
    if (extension.equals("xlsx")) {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);//lee la primera hoja del archivo
        rows = sheet.iterator();
    } else {
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(POIFSFileSystem.create(file));
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        rows = sheet.iterator();
    }
    List<Row> list = getRows(rows);//guarda las filas en una lista
    System.out.println(value(list, 3, 4));
}

public List<Row> getRows(Iterator<Row> rows) {
    XSSFRow row;
    List<Row> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
        list.add(row);
    }
    return list;
}

public String value(List<Row> rows, int numRow, int numColumn) {
    String result = "";
    Row row = rows.get(numRow);//obtiene la fila especifica
    if (row != null) {
        var cells = row.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            XSSFCell cel = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
            if (cel.getColumnIndex() == numColumn) {//obtiene la celda especifica
                if (cel.getCellType() != CellType.NUMERIC) { //si el valor es numerico
                    result = cel.getStringCellValue();
                } else {
                    int num = (int) cel.getNumericCellValue();
                    result = Integer.toString(num);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```